# Calculate week time between dates in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have two days:

```
$from = "2021-08-02";
$to = "2021-08-15";
$weekDiff = ceil(abs(strtotime($startDate) - strtotime($endDate)) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7);
```

I got the number of weeks starting from Monday.
But I have a problem I want help with.

If I choose `$from = "2021-08-03"` for Tuesday or $from = "2021-08-04" for Wednesday, then i want it to default to monday `$from = "2021-08-02"`.
If I select $form = "2021-08-05" as a Thursday, I want it to start from Thursday to Sunday. Thanks

Comment: It is unclear how the weeks should be counted.
A few more examples with $from,  $to, and the expected value of the weeks are helpful.